# Custom controller without sharing - cannot edit inputField for Guest user

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites

I'm developing on a scratch org with [Salesforce Sites](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_platform_portal_implementation_guide.meta/salesforce_platform_portal_implementation_guide/sites_setup_overview.htm) enabled.

My Visualforce page code:

```
 <apex:page controller="myAccountController">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:inputField value="{!account.Name }"/>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!save }" value="save" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Custom controller:

```
public class MyAccountController {
public MyAccountController() {
  this.account = [
      SELECT Id, Name
      FROM Account
      WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')
    ];
}

public Account account {get;set;}
public PageReference save() {
    update account;
    return null;
  }
}
```

The [Public Access Settings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_platform_portal_implementation_guide.meta/salesforce_platform_portal_implementation_guide/sites_public_access_settings.htm) has Edit Access checked on the Account Field-Level Security.

The inputField displays but I can't edit it. What do I need to do to make it editable? Thank you

Comment: the fact that you are displaying `$User.FirstName` suggests you have authenticated users on this Community (as otherwise, this value makes no sense for guest users). This would imply you need to look at some Community user profile for CRUD

Comment: sorry `$User.FirstName` was just pasted from an example. It's really the Guest User.

Comment: What is the "external access" setup on this object (sharing settings - OWD)? Is it private or read only?

Comment: @KannanNarayanan I've updated the post to include custom controller code. It doesn't have `with sharing`. Which external access settings would I need to modify?

Comment: This [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.security_owd_external.htm&type=5) says "Guest users aren't considered external users. Guest users’ org-wide defaults are set to Private for all objects, and this access level can’t be changed."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to see the field as editable and did the below:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" showHeader="false" cache="false" lightningStylesheets="true" applyHtmlTag="true">
   <apex:form >
      <apex:inputField value="{!account.Name}"/>
      <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="save" />
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

On VF page, `Available for Lightning Experience, Experience Builder sites, and the mobile app` i enabled this.

***Profile:***

I gave `Read` and `Create` access on Guest User License, and also made sure i added my VF page to `Visualforce Page access`.

Below is my site detail screen if it helps.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to make the inputField editable:

```
<apex:page controller="myAccountController">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:inputField value="{!account.Name }" ignoreEditPermissionForRendering="true"/>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!save }" value="save" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Set [ignoreEditPermissionForRendering](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputField.htm) to 'true'.